# Loop Through Records, Update one Record, and Exit

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select all records from my table and loop through all those records until I get to the record where the numtimespaid column is equal to 0. Once I find that column I want to update it to 2 for that record and then exit out. Here is what I have that is not working correctly:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM ".$line." ORDER BY datestamp, timestamp";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    if ($row[numtimespaid] == 0) {
        $queryupdate="UPDATE ".$line." SET numtimespaid=1";
        $resultu=mysql_query($queryupdate);
        break;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong and/or the right way of doing this?

Comment: So even if there is more than 1 row with numtimespaid = to 0, you want to only update the first 1 you find?

Answer (score 5):

There is no need whatsoever to loop over rowset from a `SELECT` statement. You can simply update the first row with that value. This query will update exactly one record matching `numtimespaid = 0`. If you want to update all rows matching that criterion, just remove the `LIMIT 1`.

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE $line SET numtimespaid=1 WHERE numtimespaid = 0 ORDER BY datestamp, timestamp LIMIT 1");
```

By the way, we don't know what the contents of `$line` are, but hopefully you have properly filtered that value if it comes from user input.  If it does comes from user input, it's recommended to check its value against a whitelist of possible table names:

```
// $line can be one of table1,table2,table3
if (!in_array($line, array('table1','table2','table3')) {
  // FAIL, don't execute the query
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response back. I actually would like to make it numtimespaid == 0 or 1. I will try this out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($row[numtimespaid] == 0) {
```

Generally gets interpreted as numtimespaid being an undefined constant. Put quotes around it, like this:

```
if ($row['numtimespaid'] == 0) {
```

Then, realize Michael's answer is just better overall.

Comment: Thanks Umbrella, I'll experiment with this as well.